# Chrome starts buffering from seeking point in OGG file, but not in MP3 file

Tags: google-chrome, mp3, html5-audio, buffering, ogg

I've set up an HTML5 audio-tag with two sources, an OGG-file and an MP3-file, as follows:

```
<audio controls="controls" id="audioplayer1">
    <source src="podcast.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
    <source src="podcast.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
</audio>
```

When playing the OGG-file in Chrome and seeking to an unbuffered position, buffering halts at its old position and continues from this new position, so playback continues almost immediately. This also works correctly for MP3 in Internet Explorer 9 and for OGG in Firefox 14.0.1 & Opera 12.01 build 1532. However, when playing the MP3-file in Chrome, buffering simply keeps on going from the start and playback halts until the buffering reaches the new playback position. For a large audio file, this may take some time. Example: http://mvcpeer.be/uhbpmedia/web/test.html

My server should be properly configured:

```
AddType audio/mpeg mp3
AddType audio/ogg ogg
```

and byte-ranges are supported. I compared the requests the browser makes for OGG and MP3 and noticed something strange:

For OGG, Chrome first makes a request containing `Range: bytes=0-`, it receives a 206-response containing the total filesize in its header (136.320.012 bytes in this example) as follows:

REQUEST

```
GET /audio/podcast.ogg HTTP/1.1
Host: inderdaad.be
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Encoding: identity;q=1, *;q=0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.83 Safari/537.1
Accept: */*
Referer: http://mvcpeer.be/uhbpmedia/web/web.php
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Range: bytes=0-
```

RESPONSE

```
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Date: Mon, 27 Aug 2012 18:18:41 GMT
Server: Apache/2
Last-Modified: Mon, 27 Aug 2012 10:08:56 GMT
ETag: "26016c4-820140c-4c83c837ab335"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 136.320.012
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Content-Range: bytes 0-136320011/136320012
Keep-Alive: timeout=1, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: audio/ogg
```

When I skip to an unbuffered position, a second request is made to a little part at the end of the file, the property `Range:` is then `bytes=136241821-136255487` (probably for some metadata, response is 200), followed by a third request with `Range:` set to `bytes=37340471-136242175` (response 206). Buffering now starts from this point.

However for MP3, Chrome only makes one request containing `Range: bytes=0-`. No second or third request is made when I seek to an unbuffered position, and so buffering cannot start at the seeking point.

Is this a Chrome issue? (using Chrome 21.0.1180.83 m)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi. Half a year ago, I faced the same issue. Now I checked it again in current Chrome 24 (Windows). It seems that it is fixed! Now I see normal range requests, and the seek is fast. Can you confirm my observation?

Comment: The problem persists in Chrome 37